# What does this phrase mean: «smth isn't exists»?

Tags: phrase-meaning

there are many examples over internet where this exactly form is used:
«This page isn't exists» or «The file isn't exists»

does it mean the same as «smth doesn't exist»?

Comment: Please visit [English language for Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister-site. Your question is very basic for native speakers, and as such considered off-topic for this site. ELL was created for those speakers of other languages who wish to perfect their English. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's probably what it means, but it is not English.

I'll repeat that: It is not English.

It is either generated by an automatic system which cannot cope with English, or more likely has been written by somebody whose knowledge of English is limited.

Comment: I have great respect for your knowledge and command of the English language, but I really feel you could have said exactly the same thing in a comment and encouraged the user to do some research  or expand more on his question. At the very least direct the newcomer to ELL.

Comment: Fair comment, @Mari-LouA